# insert line break php function

Tags: php, function

I have an issue where I'm showing boxes of some posts from my database in a foreach loop.

The length of the post title affects the design. For example if one post has a long title next to one with a short title, it will push the link i have below down. This makes it look uneven.

Therefor I'm trying to write a function that checks if the length is too short, it should insert a line break.

This is what I have so far.

```
function insert_line_break($text){
    if (strlen($text) < 10 ) {
        echo "<br>";
    }
} 

<?= insert_line_break($entry["title"]) ?>
```

However that seems to replace the title with a linebreak.

What am I missing?

Comment: Use CSS for styling instead. :-)

Comment: The code you posted doesn't echo the text at any point so...

Comment: You could use "\n" instead of "<br />"

Comment: @piedude, have you found a suitable solution in any of those # answers? If not, tell us more. Otherwise do and accept the solution that is best for you to close the question - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

You have missed to echo the text itself.

```
function insert_line_break($text){
    if (strlen($text) < 10 ) {
        return "<br>";
    }
} 

<?php echo $entry["title"] . insert_line_break($entry["title"]); ?>
```

Note: 
I changed the function to `return` a value instead of echoing it to the output, so it will be much more reusable in the future.

And I expanded the short tag `<?` to `<?php` and made the `=` to verbose `echo` which is much clearer and readable way of coding.

And of course I closed the line with semicolon `;` as it should be.

EDIT:

`<?php echo $entry["title"] . insert_line_break($entry["title"]); ?>`

`echo` prints the content of `$entry["title"]` and then ask function `insert_line_break($entry["title"])` to decide whether it contains string shorter than 10 characters, if so it returns `<br>` that is echoed. And that's  it.

Comment: I tried this but I wasn't able to make it work. Why are you using title twice?